# Selection highlight in accordance to text input

Tags: pyqt4, highlight, qlistwidget, qlineedit

I am trying to highlight the item in my list upon the input of the text in the LineEdit but however, not only am I unable to get it to work but it also does not highlights the item in the List. Am I writing it wrong somewhere? Any advices?

```
fruitsList = QListWidget()
list01 = ['Apple','Pear','Orange','Grape','Lychee']
self.fruitsList.addItems(list01)

textInput = QLineEdit()
fruitTxt = str(textInput)

self.connect(self.textInput,('returnPressed()'), self.updateSelect)

def updateSelect(self):
    self.fruitsList.findItems(str(fruitTxt), flags = Qt.MatchExactly)
    self.fruitsList.setCurrentIndex(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with the code you posted.

The signal connection should use `QtCore.SIGNAL('returnPressed()')`. But it would be even better to use the [new-style syntax](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html), which is much less error-prone.

Your signal handler also has a couple of problems. You need to use the `text()` method of the line-edit to retrieve the current text, and use the return value of `findItems()` to select the items in the list.

Here's a little demo that shows how it might be done:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.fruitsList = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        items = 'Apple Pear Orange Grape Lychee'.split()
        self.fruitsList.addItems(items)
        self.textInput = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.textInput.returnPressed.connect(self.updateSelect)
        self.textInput.setFocus()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.fruitsList)
        layout.addWidget(self.textInput)

    def updateSelect(self):
        self.fruitsList.clearSelection()
        for item in self.fruitsList.findItems(
            self.textInput.text(), QtCore.Qt.MatchFixedString):
            item.setSelected(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 300, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```